# Laravel routes with Vue.js routes

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, single-page-application

I am developing a [content management system (CMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) application using Laravel and Vue.js, so I want to achieve these:

- I want use Vue.js routing for [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)
- I want to use Laravel routing for the administrator side

And here is the problem:

- If I use the below approach, administrator will not work

```
  return view('welcome');
    })->where('any','.*');
```

- If I use the other way around, SPA will throw 404 error message

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both routers to return your HTML. You have to make a choice here.

Since you want an SPA, you will have to use the Vue.js router to navigate within your view/route.
Your Laravel application will be used as an API endpoint to get the data (as JSON format probably).